# Missing Value in ErrorListPlot

Tags: plotting, missing

I have two lists (of data points and error_y) automatically defined for the usage in ErrorListPlots. Sometimes it happens due to the used data, that a list has only one element and then the standard deviation makes no sense, so let's assume the lists look like this:

```
q0c7ELPD = {{100, 1.70, 0.21}, {105, 1.91, 0.1}, {110, 2.5, 0.3},
{115, 2.3, 0.2}, {120, 2.4, 0.1}, {125, 2.1, 0.2}, {130, 1.9, 0.1}, {135, 2.0, 0.3}};
q0c7B24PlusELPD = {{119.5, 2.0, 0.2}, {124.5, 1.7, StandardDeviation[{1.7}]}, 
{129.5, 2.1, 0.1}, {134.5, 2.2, 0.3}};
```

Up to now I used **Mathematica 10.2** and when plotting both lists via `ErrorListPlot`

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
ErrorListPlot[{q0c7ELPD, q0c7B24PlusELPD}, PlotRange -> {{98, 142}, {0, 3}}]
```

The point with the missing sensible error (missing yellow point at x=124.5) was just left out:
[image]

I don't know whether this was a bug or a feature but it fitted my purpose very well.

Now I changed to **version 11.3** and I get an error:

[image]

I'd like to reproduce the behavior of the older version and haven't had any good idea yet. The problem is, that my lists (many of them) are created via functions and I just can't easily take out the data point by hand for every of them.

In the documentation (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Missing.html) I found a sentence "Visualization typically automatically filters out Missing elements". But obviously this doesn't work in my specific case.

Since I always got nice hints and ideas in this forum, I decided to post this question as well. So in case anybody has an idea, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: `StandardDeviation[{1.7}]` does not appear to be correct syntactically. If you evaluate it by itself it gives an error: "StandardDeviation::shlen: The argument {1.7} should have at least two elements." Please try to fix that and see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: @ Carl Lange Yes I know, but since the lists are generated automatically I can't prevent this from time to time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to give the same behavior:

```
filtered=DeleteCases[q0c7B24PlusELPD,{_,_,_StandardDeviation}];

ErrorListPlot[{q0c7ELPD, filtered}, PlotRange -> {{98, 142}, {0, 3}}]
```